# How to run Django app with Gunicorn/WSGI webserver?

Tags: django, wsgi, gunicorn, django-cache-machine

I have my existing Django application running locally on my MacBook. It's directory structure looks something like this:

```
myproject/
    mySite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    myApp1/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        views.py
    manage.py
    requirements.txt
```

Up until now, I have been using the Django toy webserver to run my app: `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. But now I want to use gunicorn instead. So I'm following the instructions [**here**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/).

I do  `source myVirtualenv/bin/activate && cd myproject && gunicorn mySite.wsgi`. I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "myproject/MyApp2/models.py", line 11, in <module>
    from caching.base import CachingManager, CachingMixin
ImportError: No module named caching.base
```

When I run `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` from the same location it works perfectly fine.

Why? Am I doing something wrong?
Does Django-Cache-Machine not work with Gunicorn/WSGI? How to work around this issue?

Comment: How have you installed gunicorn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have installed gunicorn globally rather than within the virtualenv, so the executable is pointing to the global Python and its site-packages directory rather than the one within the virtualenv. Reinstall gunicorn locally.

Answer (score 2):

To run your project using gunicorn, try the following:

1. activate your virtualenv
2. go to your project's directory
3. run `gunicorn mySite.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8000`

If the commands work fine, than my you are setup. Otherwise, try the following tutorial. I always use this tutorial myself, when setting up a new project for production. Try it. [Setting up Django with Nginx, Gunicorn and Supervisor](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/)

Comment: Thanks. There shouldn't be an issue with the VirtualEnv. You can see here that in the exact same directory and virtualenv Django's toy webserver works, but gunicorn fails: https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/58189c46aa1feff0f90ae5ef718f8d05